# How to round Int with two digits using NSNumberFormatter?

Tags: ios, swift

I simply created extensions:

```
extension NumberFormatter {
    convenience init(digits: Int) {
        self.init()
        self.maximumFractionDigits = digits
        self.minimumFractionDigits = digits
    }
}
extension Int {
    var descriptivePrice: String {
        return NumberFormatter(digits: 2).string(from: NSNumber(value: Double(self * 100/10000))) ?? ""
    }
}
```

And testing this:

```
func testDescriptivePrice() {
    XCTAssertEqual(2345.descriptivePrice, "23,45") //23,00
    XCTAssertEqual(20000.descriptivePrice, "200,00")
    XCTAssertEqual(20.descriptivePrice, "0,20") //0,00
    XCTAssertEqual(2.descriptivePrice, "0,02") //0,00
}
```

Why my tests fail?

Comment: It should be `Double(self) * 100/10000` rather than `Double(self * 100/10000)`... Is that a typo or a genuine misunderstanding?

Comment: Off topic but your tests would also fail if you ran them with the "wrong" locale so I think it would be best to use dependency injection and set the locale for your number formatter so you can set the expected locale for your tests. Perhaps change the header of the init to `convenience init(digits: Int, locale: Locale = .current) {`

Comment: Why don't you use `Decimal` instead of `Int`? Just make sure to always use the string initializer. Btw this will create a new number formatter instance every time you call this property and no need to convert your value to `NSNumber`. You can use Formatter's method `string(for: Any)` instead of NumberFormatter's method 
`string(from: NSNumber)`

Comment: @JoakimDanielson this wont make a difference with numberStyle set to none.

Comment: @LeoDabus Not for the code as it is but if one, like you suggests, use a static formatter then it will yield different result depending on what Locale object you send it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with number formatters, and everything about how you convert your ints to doubles:

```
Double(self * 100/10000)
```

Here you are converting to `Double` *after* you divide, so you are doing integer division. In other words, you are just removing the last two digits of an integer. In `2345.descriptivePrice` for example, the `45` part is already lost when you do `234500 / 10000` (= 23), before any `NumberFormatter`-related stuff happens.

You should convert `self` to `Double` first, then divide:

```
Double(self) / 100
```

Comment: In your way from `20000` I got `200,0` instead of `200,00`. I always need two digits after dot.

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk I can't reproduce. Can you post a [mcve], ideally on an online compiler like repl.it?

Comment: just try: `20000.descriptivePrice` from function `String(Double(self * 100/10000))`

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk uhh why did you use `String(...)`? You should still use `NumberFormatter` like before. And you didn’t seem to change what I asked you to change at all. Please, read my answer again.

Comment: I misunderstood you. Now I have it like this: `NumberFormatter(digits: 2).string(from: NSNumber(value: Double(self) * 100/10000)) ?? ""` and it is working of course. Thank you.